# CSS animation doesnt work after onload angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I create a div that is show while the page is loaded. The code is:

```
<div ng-show="load" class="rb-animate-time rb-animate-hide rb-load">
    <div class="text">Hello world</div>
</div>
<div ng-init="load = false"></div>
```

The div is hide after most of the page load, only some async stuffs are loading after the div be hide.

But I tried to apply an animation when the div is hide, follow the CSS:

```
.rb-load {
  background-color: #A1B1B6;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  display: table;
  z-index: 50000;
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
}
.rb-load.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}
.rb-load .text {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-bold: "flexomedium";
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #C9620D;
}
```

This animations doesn't work after the page load, but it works if I change the visibility using an angular event, like a ng-clik:

```
<button ng-click="load =!load">Load</button>
```

Why the animation doesn't happens when the page is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Add your class for anomation using `ng-class`.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass